# parsing HTML5 with Enlive/Tagsoup/JSoup

Tags: clojure, enlive, tag-soup

HTML5 allows `<meta>` tags to appear in the body, but Enlive does not seem to support this:

```
(deftest test-enlive
  (testing "enlive"
    (let [html-as-string "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><body><div><meta foo=\"bar\"><span>the content</span></body></html>"
          parsed-html (enlive/html-resource (java.io.StringReader. html-as-string))
          span (enlive/select parsed-html [ :div  :span ])
          content (first (map enlive/text span))]
      (is (= "the content" content)))))
```

This test fails, but will pass if you remove the meta tag.

[This old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/enlive-clj/zjKsnL48Z6s/xoRJ_7PXwxYJ) led me to realize that it was the meta tag that was causing a problem.

I realize that Enlive depends on Tagsoup, but when I switch it out for JSoup (which claims to support HTML5) I get the same result.

Comment: Though I’m not sure if it would change this behavior, [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) actually requires a `<meta>` tag have the `name` attribute to be used anywhere “metadata content is expected”. Since your example doesn’t have a `name` attribute, your HTML(5) is not valid.

Comment: Adding the 'name' attribute produces the same test failure. And unfortunately these kinds of tags abound in the wild.

Comment: please open an issue for this one, thanks

Comment: Opened: https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/issues/123

Comment: Issue has been closed on Jul 10 '15.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP found a solution by posting an issue to Enlive on github directly.